# K or P Colorable

Tags: graph-theory

For any p > 1 find a p-chromatic graph such that all its subgraphs (except itself) are (p − 1)−colorable.

Is there any good example for this exercise? I need feedback.

Comment: Try the complete graph on $p$ vertices.

Comment: but meaning p-1 would contradict the fact that a complete graph should have p-colorable vertices for any K^p graph with p vertices

Comment: I do not see how the chromatic number should be less than p-1 for a complete graph. It is not possible? Is it?

Comment: @ExoPrimes The complete graph *is* $p$-colourable, as in the type of graph you're supposed to find.

Answer (score 1):

I think a the complete graph on 3 vertices would work here as an example, so basically an equilateral triangle. Because the chromatic number is 3, but then all the subgraphs have chromatic number 2, because if you remove an edge from the triangle, then you only need 2 colors to color all vertices. I think this would work, unless there is something else that I am not reading correctly that would make this more complicated.